# C# list where items have a TTL

Tags: c#, data-structures

For sake of a simple example, I'd like to have a list of strings.  Each item in the list should "expire" 5 minutes after adding it to the list.  Although there may not be an easy, built-in way to do this, I'd like to end up with a data structure whose API feels like it "just works".

You might use it as follows:

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var list = new ListWithTTL<string>();
list.add("Bob", now);
list.add("Joe", now.AddMinutes(1));
list.add("Tom", now.AddMinutes(2));
list.add("Tim", now.AddMinutes(2));
```

Inspecting elements immediately would yield

```
["Bob", "Joe", "Tom", "Tim"]
```

A few minutes later it should yield

```
["Tom", "Tim"]
```

Eventually the list should be empty.

Comment: Just looking for ideas for an implementation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use the [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class in .NET 4 which allows you to specify a TTL when you add an item.

Simple example:

```
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("foo");
cache.Add("bar", "baz", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
var bar = cache["bar"];//returns "baz"
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
var expired = cache["bar"]; //returns null
```

While not providing you directly with a TTL list you could adapt this for your solution, no need to implement cache expiration yourself.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that... much better +1

Comment: +1 This is why I read stackoverflow every day. To learn stuff.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Will items be ever be evicted from `MemoryCache` **before** their TTL expires? For example, what happens when `MemoryCache.CacheMemoryLimit` is reached?

Comment: The link is no more available, use this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and switch throw different framework versions

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `SortedDictionary<DateTime, ...>` and a custom `IComparer<DateTime>` that "reverses" the order of the dictionary so the oldest elements come first. Before returning elements from the dictionary, simply remove first N elements that are too old.

Of course, modifying collection "under the covers" when caller is expecting a simple read may lead to problems in multi-threaded environment, but this is a different topic...